# How can I remove Ubuntu 12.04.?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I just bought a Dell and it has this weird thing called ubuntu. I dont like it and want to use windows 7 . Please help me uninstall it. I dont have anything saved on it so I don't care if data is removed.

My dell has no CD drive , Its a little laptop.

Comment: Since you need Windows 7, why don't you search at Microsoft for help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/installing-and-reinstalling-windows-7?

Comment: Before you bought the computer, you should take note of the operating system installed, that is, Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You need any *partion manager* to remove Ubuntu file systems ("**/**", and "**/home**") and **linux swap**. (If say more simply - **delete everything**). Then make one (or some, if you want) **NTFS's** and install there your Windows from flash drive (You can search in web about it).

*P.S. My English in not very well, so maybe I make many mistakes. I tell you in advance thanks, if you will fix them.*